# functor overloading best practices

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, functor

Hi I am trying to get to grips with functors. Here is a simple example

```
struct A {
 double b,c;
 A(const double bb, const double cc) : b(bb), c(cc) {}
 double operator()(const double x, const double y) {
  return b*c*x*y;
 }
};
```

I would like to know if it is possible to overload A such that it could be passed `b`, `c` and also e.g. `x` reusing the code in the `operator()`. My overall interest is to not have to re-write lengthy code in operators multiple times and to better understand the best practices for doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `b(bb), c(cc)` be `b(b), c(c)`?

Comment: Be passed `a`?  What/where is that?

Comment: @Chad I meant `b`, `c` or `x`

Comment: @Galik my compiler is happy with the above form

Comment: Where in the constructor, do you feel the need to reuse a code that does `b * c * x * y` ?

Comment: @fen your code above does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to overload A such that it could be passed b, c and also e.g. x reusing the code in the operator().

Yes, it is not difficult to do that.

```
double operator()(double x, double y) // Remove the const. It's useless.
{
   // Call the other overload using the member data.
   return (*this)(b, c, x, y);
}

double operator()(double bb, double cc, double x, double y)
{
   // Not using any member data at all.
   return bb*cc*x*y;
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu Your solution is working in my code. Many thanks for getting straight to the point and in particular answering the question that was asked!

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing this is with `std::bind` in `<functional>`.  This returns a closure that you can call without arguments.  An alternative would be to create a new constructor with default arguments for `a` and `b`, or a derived class, and overload it to have:

```
double operator()(const double x = m_x, const double y = m_y);
```

As a side note, please don't use the same names for members and arguments of member functions; that creates ambiguity about which you mean and could even cause bugs if you rename a parameter later.